# How to hide PRAGMA KEY in sqlcipher?

Tags: sql, security, sqlcipher

I use sqlcipher to encrypt the database

While connecting to the database, I use on the command line PRAGMA KEY = "test" to decrypt the database. How can I hide this entry, because I have to present my work, but they may reprimand me for entering the key so openly?

Comment: Which dbms is this for? The <sql> tag is for the ISO/IEC SQL standard.